# how to let a form field be hidden and at the same time the value be able to acces the id using javascript?

Tags: 7, forms

How can I get the #value of a hidden form field in javscript as for hidden form
 field I am unable to get its id in the (inspect element) html.
How can I extract the value(#value) for the field using ajax for the hidden fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$form['hidden'] = array(
 '#type' => 'hidden',
 '#value' => 'Your_value',
 '#attributes' => array('id' => array('your_id')),
);
```

Now using javascript or jquery you get the value of the hidden field.

In jquery:  `jQuery("#your_id").val();`